# Kivy , Python: Update Label on_file_drop

Tags: python, label, kivy

I'm trying to do a very simple GUI which can update a text label when a file it's being dropped on the application.

So far i've been able to recognize when a file is being dropped and print a message on the console. Unfortunately now i have been trying to update a label (with message "Linkin Park") to "Three Day Grace" when a file is dropped, but i have not make it yet.

May anyone help me to solve mi question?

**main.py**

```
#Se importan archivos necesarios de Kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import random

class MainLayout(FloatLayout):

    artistName = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.artistName = "Linkin Park"

    def _on_file_drop(self):
        self.artistName = "Three Day Grace"
        print "File Dropped"

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Shantazam"
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self._on_file_drop)
        Window.size = (400,700)
        return MainLayout()

    def _on_file_drop(self, window, file_path):
        file_path = file_path.split("\\")
        fileToOpen = file_path[-2]+"\\"+file_path[-1]
        print(enter code herefileToOpen)
        MainLayout()._on_file_drop()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**MainApp.kv**

```
 #:import utils kivy.utils


<MainLayout>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0088ff')

        Rectangle:
            pos: 0,0
            size: self.size

    Label:
        text: 'Shantazam'
        font_size: 72
        markup: True
        shorten: True
        ellipsis_options: {'color':(1,0.5,0.5,1),'underline':True}
        size_hint: (1, 0.17)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0 , 'y' : 0.7}
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: root.artistName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a reference to your `MainLayout`, so that you can access `artistName`. If you adjust your `App` to:

```
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Shantazam"
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self._on_file_drop)
        Window.size = (400,700)
        self.mainLayout = MainLayout()
        return self.mainLayout

    def _on_file_drop(self, window, file_path):
        self.mainLayout.artistName = 'Three Day Grace'
```

I think it will work.